# Parse Var & Perform Calculations

Tags: javascript, jquery, paypal

I am having an issue with a bit of code in a form.  I am trying to get the value from the user (dollar amount) and parse it to an integer.  Then I need to perform calculations to add 2.9% to it and also add .30 to the product.

It seems that the issue is in the parsing...because I am getting errors in the console saying `$sendAmount.val is not a function` [when I enter `$sendAmount.val()`]. Yet, if I submit `$userAmount.val()`, it returns the dollar amount the user submitted (in a string).

Keep in mind that `$userAmount` is what the user enters and
`$sendAmount` is what is sent to Paypal.

Any help with this would be most appreciated... I have been trying to get this to work and have been coming up empty.  I don't have much experience with parseInt.

Here is my code:

```js
  var $sendAmount = $("#payAMT");
var $userAmount = $("#valInput");

//Update the Amount
function $convFee() {
  $sendAmount = parseInt($userAmount) * 1.029 + 0.30;
};

$agree.keyup($convFee);
$agree.click($convFee);
```

```html
<div id="paypalWrap">
  <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="new">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" id="payAMT" value="0.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <p>
      <label for="os0" type="hidden" name="on0" value="Name:">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="os0" maxlength="30" id="name">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="os1" type="hidden" name="on1" value="Invoice Number:">Invoice Number:
        <br />
        <i>(Reference must be correct to get credit applied to your account)</i>
      </label>
      <input type="text" name="os1" maxlength="50" id="invoice">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="os2" type="hidden" name="on2" value="Amount:">Amount being paid:</label>
      <input type="text" name="os2" id="valInput" maxlength="15" placeholder="ex: 10.00 (not $10.00)">
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" name "agreeCheck" id="agreeCheck" />
      <label for="agreeCheck" type="hidden" name="agreeStatement" id="agreeStatement">
        I understand and accept that I will be charged a convenience fee ($0.30 + 2.9% of transaction).
      </label>
    </p>

    <input id="send" type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" disabled="disabled" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: parseInt($userAmount) doesnt seem like it would work because you are trying to parse a jquery object which does not represent a number. Maybe try parsing $userAmount.val()

Comment: ^Was writing an answer to the same effect, but this question seems minor/specific enough to just warrant your comment.

Comment: I had tried that earlier, but am was getting errors:

$userAmount.val()
""
$sendAmount.val()
"0.00"
$userAmount.val()
"10"
$sendAmount.val()
"0.00"
4payment.html:269 Uncaught TypeError: $sendAmount.val is not a function$decide @ payment.html:269jQuery.event.dispatch @ jquery.js:4411jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4097
$userAmount.val()
"10"
$sendAmount.val()
VM5660:2 Uncaught TypeError: $sendAmount.val is not a function(anonymous function) @ VM5660:2InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ VM5654:883InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ VM5654:816InjectedScript.evaluate @ VM5654:682

Comment: It seems the issue with what you tried is that you were using `$sendAmount.val`, where you should have called `$sendAmount.val()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line has the same problem twice:

$sendAmount = parseInt($userAmount) * 1.029 + 0.30;

Both of these variables are DOM elements, not numbers. You need to interact with them as items, specifically their value elements (which are strings that can be parsed to numbers).

You need to retrieve the value from the first, and set the value of the second, e.g.:

$sendAmount.val(parseInt($userAmount.val) * 1.029 + 0.30);

See http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: I used this as:  
$sendAmount.val(parseInt($userAmount.val() ) * 1.029 + 0.30);

This worked!  Thanks!